# Formula for three different color options for Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have two columns of dates, both are linked to another database and update automatically when that is adjusted. The left column, "Plan" will always remain white. I need help with the formatting of the right, or the "Actual" column. These dates will be updated as they are either reached on-time, early or late.

I have already created a Conditional Format that turns dates that are "equal to or before" to green and any dates that happen "after" to red. The part I now need help with is turning any dates that happen in the future to white. To summarize:

```
Actual > Plan: highlight Actual red, 
Actual <= Plan: highlight Actual green, 
Actual > Today's date: highlight Actual white
```

*Sidenote: The Actual date is assumed to happen on Plan until it happens either late or early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dates for Actual and Plan then your reds and greens cover every possibility. So your 'special case' must override the other rules. Since "(applied in order shown)" put it at the top (or move it to the top). Something like your rule for red should suit, with larger than TODAY().

Comment: I'm still having trouble, I create a new rule: use a formula to determine which cells to format: =A1>TODAY()...I then put this rule on top as you suggested and the cell remains green, any suggestions?

Comment: Yes I put it on top which I thought would cure it because I did not have it on top before you suggested that, but for some reason it changes nothing

Comment: I have it working now, I believe my problem was trying to highlight the entire row at once to input the formula was not working, but when I selected one cell then just used format painter for the entire row it worked...your tip of making sure the rule was on top was very helpful though, thank you very much